# BSON Parser for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bson

I'm writing an App (in swift 5 for iOS) that reads some mqtt messages coming from a remote mqtt broker. The messages format is BSON (Binary Json). Is there any library or code that allows me to read the message in this format? With the standard library for Swift I can read and decode normal JSON Files but not BSON. Some suggestion?

Comment: @Sulthan The official name is BSON not BJSON. I found a library.

Comment: @Sulthan The JSON and BSON format are standard based on ECMA-262. Is not true there are multiple standard. There are multiple object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this library: https://github.com/OpenKitten/BSON
After installed the package in Xcode (using packet manager) I was able to read the BSON file received from Mqtt broker

Here the code I used:

```
//At the beginning of the file
import BSON

...
...

//I use BSON Document object to read the payload of the message
let info = Document(bytes: message.payload)
//I use the function isValid to check if the format is correct
if info.validate().isValid{
   //If the format is correct I can read a field of the Json (in the example "MessageType")
   let messageType:String = info["MessageType"] as? String ?? ""
   ...
   ...
```